# CustomValidator woes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, customvalidator

Ok iv followed more than a few of the CustomValidators for multiple asp CheckBox's on here and on a few other sites and am having a little bit of a hard time with it actually validating when a check box is checked.

Whilst I have tried a variety of answers I have settled on one in particular.
I have gotten it to the point that it will show in the validation summary but when the checkbox's are checked they still show up in the summary that they are not. I don't know what iv done wrong or if I have missed something but i'm hoping an extra set of eyes can help me with what I have missed.

CheckBox's:

```
<div class="section">
    <span>2</span>Induction Checklist:
</div>
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Introduction of relevant staff <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbStaffIntro" /></label>
     <label>Comments: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStaffIntroComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Location of all Exits <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbExitLocations" /></label>
    <label>Comments: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtExitLocationComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Evacuation Assembly Point <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbEvacuationPoint" /></label>
    <label>Comments: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEvacuationPointComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
     <label>Location of Fire Extinguishers <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbFireExtLocations" /></label>
      <label>Comments: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFireExtLocationsComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Location of Fire Hoses <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbFireHoseLoc" /></label>
    <label>Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFireHoseLocComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Location of First Aid Kits <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbFirstAidLoc" /></label>
    <label>Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstAidLocComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
      <label>Location of Male / Female Toilets <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbLooLoc" /></label>
    <label>Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLooLocComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Location of Lunch Rooms <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbLuncLoc" /></label>
    <label>Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLunchLocComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Explain "No-Smoking" Policy in all Offices and Buildings <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbNoSmoke" /></label>
     <label>Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNoSmokeComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Explain and Indicate "No-Go" Zones in Warehouse <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbNoGo" /></label>
    <label>Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNoGoComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->

<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Other <asp:CheckBox CssClass="HitCheckbox" ValidationGroup="checkList" runat="server" ID="cbOther" /></label>
     <label>Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherComment" /></label>
</div> <!-- end inner-wrap -->
```

Client side validation:

```
<script>
function CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate(sender, e)
{
    e.IsValid = jQuery(".HitCheckBox input:checkbox").is(':checked');
}
</script>
```

Server Side Validation:

```
public void Required_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = (cbStaffIntro.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbExitLocations.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbEvacuationPoint.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbFireExtLocations.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbFireHoseLoc.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbFirstAidLoc.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbLooLoc.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbLuncLoc.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbNoSmoke.Checked);
    args.IsValid = (cbNoGo.Checked);
}
```

Custom Validators:

```
<!-- Checklist Validation Section cbStaffIntro -->
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorSi" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Introduction to relevant Staff Not Completed!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorEl" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Emergancy Exit Locations Not Completed!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorEp" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Evacuation Point Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorFe" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Fire Extinguisher Locations Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorFh" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Fire Hose Locations Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorFa" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="First Aid Locations Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorToilet" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Toilet Locations Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorLr" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Lunchroom Location Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorNsp" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="No Smoking Policy Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidatorNg" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="'No-Go' Zones Not Covered!" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
```

The way i wish this to work is all of the check box's, except for the one marked 'Other', need to be selected before the form is validated.

As mentioned, I have this to the point that they will show up in the validation summary if they are not checked. What i'm having issues with is why they are still showing up as not checked in the validation summary when they are checked.

What is it im missing here? or is what i'm after not fully possible?
Before I forget i'm using .NET Framework 4 for this project.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Scotty for their efforts in helping me with this issue. After applying the fix offered I also had to remove the Javascript validation I had to get the code to work as needed.

Comment: Why not just include a 'required' attribute (except for others) on each of the check boxes?

Comment: @abramlimpin: unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the ErrorMessages from all CustomValidators as you're using the same server side method `Required_ServerValidate` to validate all of your `CustomValidator` controls and aren't building your ErrorMessage dynamically.

You need to change your logic to dynamically build your Error Messages for each condition.

Firstly, remove all your CustomValidators except for one, then modify your code as follows.

Here's one approach...

**ASPX**

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvCheckList" ValidationGroup="checkList" EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" OnServerValidate="Required_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" />
```

Make sure you use `DisplayMode="SingleParagraph"` in your ValidationSummary so the html renders properly.

**Code Behind**

```
public void Required_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = true;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<ul>");

    if (!cbStaffIntro.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "Introduction to relevant Staff Not Completed!");

    if (!cbExitLocations.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "Emergency Exit Locations Not Completed!");

    if (!cbEvacuationPoint.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "Evacuation Point Not Covered!");

    if (!cbFireExtLocations.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "Fire Extinguisher Locations Not Covered!");

    if (!cbFireHoseLoc.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "Fire Hose Locations Not Covered!");

    if (!cbFirstAidLoc.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "First Aid Locations Not Covered!");

    if (!cbLooLoc.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "Toilet Locations Not Covered!");

    if (!cbLuncLoc.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "Lunchroom Location Not Covered!");

    if (!cbNoSmoke.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "No Smoking Policy Not Covered!");

    if (!cbNoGo.Checked)
        AppendErrorMessage(args, sb, "'No-Go' Zones Not Covered!");

    sb.Append("</ul>");
    cvCheckList.ErrorMessage = sb.ToString();
}

private static void AppendErrorMessage(ServerValidateEventArgs args, StringBuilder sb, string message)
{
    args.IsValid = false;
    sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", message);
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
        Response.Redirect("ValidationSuccessful.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code to reflect what you have shown here to test. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. It seems validation is happening along the lines somewhere, but even with all the required checkboxes filled and other validation criteria met there seems to be something flagged as not valid. 

Also the messages are not appearing at all in the validation summary.

Comment: The above works for me on a test page I set up using your code. Things to check... 1) has your ValidationSummary got a ValidationGroup? It needs to be the same as your CustomValidator i.e. ValidationGroup="checkList"? 2) Have you removed the ErrorMessage from your single CustomValidator in your ASPX? 3) If you put a breakpoint at the start of the Required_ServerValidate method, submit the form, is it actually hitting the breakpoint? If you step through the code, is the logic working? Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Scotty.

1) Yes the ValidationSummary has the ValidationGroup="checkList" within.
2) Yes the ErrorMessage="" has been removed from the customvalidator.
I have tried putting the breakpoint in for the CodeBehind and it doesnt seem to be reaching it at all.

Comment: Ok cool, at the start of your submit button method, put a Page.Validate(); call which will force the Required_ServerValidate method to run. I've added an example at the end of the code above which shows the basic idea.

Comment: Adding the Page.Validate() didnt make it kick in unfortunately. Doesnt seem to be getting that far. Could it be the javascript thats causing the issue here?

EDIT: Removed the javascript validation and it hit the server side validation method.